# Zend Framework error array to string conversion after clicking the login link

Tags: php, zend-framework

If i click the login link i get error =>

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/site/library/Zend/View/Helper/HtmlElement.php on line 104 

Call Stack: 
0.0003 335540 
1. {main}() /var/www/site/public/index.php:0 0.0682 4242800 
2. Zend_Application->run() /var/www/site/public/index.php:26 0.0683 4242800 
3. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Application.php:366 0.0684 4242872 
4. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php:97 0.0789 4866464 
5. Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php:954 0.0867 5201824 
6. Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:295 0.1095 6672344 
7. Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php:523 0.1095 6673344 
8. Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php:277 0.1096 6673344     
9. Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php:957 0.1107 6673592 
10. Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php:918 0.1107 6673592 
11. Zend_View_Abstract->render() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php:897 0.1108 6714828 
12. Zend_View->_run() /var/www/site/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php:880 0.1109 6716384     
13. include('/var/www/site/application/views/scripts/index/login.phtml') /var/www/site/library/Zend/View.php:108 0.1133 6810172 
14. Zend_Form->__toString() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Form.php:0 0.1133 6810172 
15. Zend_Form->render() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Form.php:2903 0.1168 6970720 
16. Zend_Form_Decorator_FormElements->render() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Form.php:2887 0.1336 7588600 
17. Zend_Form_Element->render() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Form/Decorator/FormElements.php:101 0.1345 7590872 
18. Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper->render() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Form/Element.php:2020 0.1362 7609432 
19. Zend_View->formPassword() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Form/Decorator/ViewHelper.php:246 0.1362 7609880 
20. Zend_View_Abstract->__call() /var/www/site/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php:0 0.1362 7610208 
21. call_user_func_array() /var/www/site/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php:342 0.1362 7610656 
22. Zend_View_Helper_FormPassword->formPassword() /var/www/site/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php:0 0.1365 7613744 
23. Zend_View_Helper_HtmlElement->_htmlAttribs() /var/www/site/library/Zend/View/Helper/FormPassword.php:89 0.1365 7614364 
24. implode() /var/www/site/library/Zend/View/Helper/HtmlElement.php:104
```

Can anyone tell why am i getting this error?

And how can i solve it ?

```
public function loginAction() {
    $obj = new Application_Form_Login();

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        if ($obj->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            if ($this->_process($obj->getValues())) {
                $this->_helper->redirector('arcade', 'index');
            }
        }
    }
    $this->view->form=$obj;
}
```

Login form =>

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName("login");
        $this->setMethod("post");

        $temp=array(array('StringLength',false,array(0,50)));

        $this->addElement('text','usr',array(
            'filters'=>array('StringTrim','StringToLower'),
            'validators'=>$temp,
            'required'=>true,
            'label'=>'Username',
        ));

        $this->addElement('password','psw',array(
            'filters'=>array('StringTrim'),
            'validator'=>$temp,
            'required'=>true,
            'label'=>'Password',
        ));

        $this->addElement('submit','log',array(
            'required'=>false,
            'ignore'=>true,
            'label'=>'Login',
        ));
    }

}
```

Comment: Please update your question. The error string is quite unreadable, try to split it up with breaks. Moreover, what link did you clicked? Any code would be very handy.

Comment: Well error is clearly Array to string conversion in /var/www/site/library/Zend/View/Helper/HtmlElement.php on line 104

Comment: I have added loginAction code.

Comment: This is 104 =>                     $val = implode(' ', $val);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like youve got something wrong in your form code in Application_Form_Login, probably an incorrect parameter when creating the elements. Looks like its to do with your password field, can you post the code for your form class?

Comment: when you are adding the password element, you have small typo "validator" should be "validators"